# Marshal.PtrToStructure works in .NET3.5 but fails in .NET4

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I have a project which, when set to be a .NET3.5 project, executes the following line and the curConnection is populated as expected.

```
var curConnection = (Connection)Marshal.PtrToStructure(currentPtr, typeof(Connection));
```

When I switch the project to be a .NET4 project, the curConnection object is not populated with the correct details anymore. Switching it back to 3.5 makes it work again, but I need to switch to .NET4 for various reasons I won't go into.

I've tried adding the following to the config, but it doesn't help.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <NetFx40_PInvokeStackResilience enabled="1"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

The currentPtr value is provided by a third party library and I don't have the source for it.
Below is the structure for Connection etc.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Connection
{
    public ConnectionId party;
    public ExtendedDevice staticDevice;
};
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct ConnectionId // 70 bytes
{
    public UInt32 CallId; // 4 bytes
    public DeviceId DeviceId; // 64 bytes
    public DeviceTypes DeviceType; // 2 bytes
};
```

...
I'm not going to provide ALL the code, but the remaining structs all look very similar.

Comment: And are you sure `currentPtr`, and what it points to, are OK in V4? Might help if you provide some details on `Connection`.

Comment: I've updated the question, fleshing out some details...
As for currentPtr, it is provided by another NON-.NET component, so I don't think .NET4 will have had an effect on it

Comment: OK. Did you verify all those sizes, starting with `sizeof(Connection)` in both versions?

Comment: I changed the version on the same project back to 3.5 and it worked perfectly, so I know it is not down to a code change.
As for the sizes, they have all been supplied

Comment: Yes, but supplied != verified.

Comment: That was not a usefull comment at all, don't know why someone would have marked you up on that...

Comment: Yes, beats me too. And no one ever solved a problem by checking what they knew to be true.